# .onClick() isn't working on jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile app which has a form and in it, there are some radio options. It's for my learning purpose.

The basic idea behind is that the app will take four physical activity name in radio buttons and then according to that name will produce a select menu dynamically.

I come up with a solution that I'll take the exercise name in radio buttons and using onClick() will modify the select menu. But unfortunately the onClick isn't working. I've searched on the net spending adequate amount of time, but I found no understandable solution.

So, I need your help. Below is my code. If you can come up with the solution, then please direct me and also mention how and why your code working here!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">


  function COptions(){
     alert("hello World!");
      //document.writeln("Hello World!");
    }  ;


  </script>

   <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" data-control-title="Home" id="page1">
      <div id="header" data-theme="a" data-role="header">
          <h3 id="header_txt">
              Calorie Burned
          </h3>
      </div>
      <form  name="form" id="form">
      <div data-role="content">
          <div class="form-input" data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput">
              <label for="textinput2">
                  Weight 
              </label>
              <input name="weight" id="textinput2" placeholder="Enter weight (in lbs) " value="" data-mini="true"
              type="number"/>
          </div>
          <div id="exercise_type" data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="radiobuttons"   >
              <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                  <legend>
                      Choose Type of Exercise:
                  </legend>
                  <input id="radio1" name="exercise_type" value="" type="radio" onClick = "COptions()"  >
                  <label for="radio1">
                      Walking
                  </label>
                  <input id="radio2" name="exercise_type" value="running" type="radio" onClick = "COptions()"  >
                  <label for="radio2">
                      Running
                  </label>
                  <input id="radio3" name="exercise_type" value="cycling" type="radio" onClick = "COptions()" >
                  <label for="radio3">
                      Cycling
                  </label>
                  <input id="radio4" name="exercise_type" value="swimming" type="radio" onClick = "COptions()" >
                  <label for="radio4">
                      Swimming
                  </label>

              </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="selectmenu">
              <label for="intensity">
                  Intensity:
              </label>
              <select id="intensity" name="intensity" data-mini="true">
                  <option value="option1">
                  </option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <input class="button" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="top" value="Submit"
          data-mini="true" type="submit">
      </div>
      <div id="footer" data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
          <h3 id="footer_txt">
              A simple calorie calculator
          </h3>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: semi colons maybe, what does the debugger say?

Comment: If I run it is works http://jsbin.com/owivof/1/edit what is wrong?

Comment: You might want to use event delegation. Use on("click"). You'll save the number of times you add onclick. Just a side note.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike normal web pages, radio buttons in jQuery Mobile works in a different way. Because real radio buttons are hidden and custom ones are shown, change event must be used instead of click event. Also if possible don't use inline javascript **`onClick`** with jQuery Mobile, do this with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page1', function(){ 
    $(document).on('change', '[name="exercise_type"]', function(){ 
        alert("hello World!");
    });
});
```

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/UEypE/